# not able to run vm using VirtualBox on fedora 28 workstation

Tags: fedora, virtualbox

I have several problems with virtualbox on fedora 28 workstation. Problems are described below:

First at all, I tried to install virtualbox following to this tutorial: 
https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-virtualbox-with-yum-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

I got stuck at step 5:  **Install VirtualBox Latest Version 5.2**

After command:

```
 dnf install VirtualBox-5.2
```

I got error: **No match for argument: VirtualBox-5.2
Error: Unable to find a match.**

I resolved this problem as described below:

I download rpm package from official site and install it with right clicking on it and **choose open with software install**

After successful installation  I created vm with win10 64bit and tried to run it and then I get this:

[image]

Of course I run **/sbin/vboxconfig** in terminal  as described in modal window but I got error : **vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.**

output from dmesg: (there are more ECPI errors)
[image]

After small research I found this article (https://gorka.eguileor.com/vbox-vmware-in-secureboot-linux-2016-update/), which looks like can solve my problem:

So I followed steps

I skipped first command because I already installed all required packages from this tutorial (virtualbox, gcc and kernel-devel)

Then I tried second command :

`sudo akmods` and get:
**No akmod packages found, nothing to do.                    [  OK  ]**

After trying third command:

```
sudo modprobe -v vboxdrv
```

**ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Operation not permitted**

So I couldnt continue....

**Questions:**

1. What should cause : **No match for argument: VirtualBox-5.2
   Error: Unable to find a match.**  ???

2.How Could I solve errors produced by  commands sudo akmods and sudo modprobe -v vboxdrv to get same result as in tutorial ?

3.I also encoutered to this **Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'virtualbox', disabling.** What does it mean ? and how could be solved ?

My virtualbox/kernel version is:

virtualbox - **v5.2.20**

fedora kernel version **4.18.14-200.fc28.x86_64**.

Comment: The error said that you should `use dmesg to find out why` the vboxdrv module didn't load. But I don't see any `dmesg` output in your question. Please run `dmesg -w` in one terminal, then run `vboxconfig` in another terminal. If it fails, you will see new messages in the first terminal, and you can copy them here.

Comment: @MichaelHampton post is updated

Comment: Are you sure those are the right messages? The system was only up for 16 seconds. That's not enough time for you to have opened terminals and run `vboxconfig`.

Comment: here is whole output https://pastebin.com/0Xza2DbY

Answer (score 0):

You can't run VirtualBox and KVM at the same time. But your system appears to be starting KVM at boot.

Try stopping and disabling the libvirtd service.

```
systemctl stop libvirtd
systemctl disable libvirtd
```

You can then either unload the KVM modules or reboot the system.

```
rmmod kvm_intel; rmmod kvm
```

At this point you should be able to install the VirtualBox modules and begin using VirtualBox.

---

But of course, if you are already using KVM, why on earth would you even want VirtualBox?

Comment: I didn't know about kvm I will try to use this instead of virtualbox

Comment: You can install `virt-manager` to have a nice GUI tool to create your VMs.

Comment: I finally found the time and install win 10 iso with kvm. Virt manager is great tool for managing VM. Thanks a lot ! So I solved my  issue. Anyway I asked my colleague and he told me that he hasn't problem with virtualbox installation.